# Setting a tikz node smaller than its label (within a matrix)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using a tikz matrix to lay out a diagram. However, I've realised I want some of the rows to be even more closely spaced than they already are. Because of this, I want to set the height of one of the nodes to be smaller than its label.

Here's an MWE to show what I mean.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \matrix[inner sep=0] {
        \node{A}; & \\
        & \node{B}; \\
        \node{C}; & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this

[image]

but imagine I wanted to squish the 'A' and the 'C' closer together so that it would look more like this

[image]

To do that using the matrix layout would, I think, require the height of the 'B' node to be less than the height of the letter 'B', so that the label overlaps the boundary of the box. Either that or it would require the letter 'B' to be just drawn on top of the node, without affecting its bounding box. Is something along these lines possible?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, a matrix might not the right tool for alignment. I assume you don't only want to align nodes that contain single letters?

Comment: @JasperHabicht that's correct, yes, I'm actually aligning nodes in a graph-like diagram. I've tried quite a few options for it and so far the matrix approach has turned out to be by far the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change inter row space for every row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \matrix[inner sep=0] {
        \node{A}; & \\[-3pt]
        & \node{B}; \\[-3pt]
        \node{C}; & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most sensible answer (feedback welcome), but here is one way using the `adjustbox` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \matrix[inner sep=0] {
        \node{A}; & \\
        & \node{\adjustbox{trim = 0pt 2pt}{B}};\\
        \node{C}; & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The 2pt parameter is how much height to trim off the top and bottom, while the 0pt is how much to trim off the left and right.

Comment: You can do this with a style: `\tikzset{trim top and bottom/.default=2pt,trim top and bottom/.style={overlay,append after command={[use as bounding box] ([yshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.south west)([yshift=-#1]\tikzlastnode.north east)}}}`